# All new entry tabs are blank (date, categories etc)

Tags: control-panel, ee

I wonder if anyone else has had problems with all the fields disappearing from new entry tabs?  I have the tabs but no drop downs etc.  I've also stopped receiving comment notifications? I'm on EE 2.10

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is while editing an entry, openening the sidebar and clicking 'Reset Layout'. You may need to save and then reopen.

This solves issues like that for me sometimes.